Fetch and Store Airflow Logs
Is there any way to fetch the airflow logs programmatically and store it in some variable ? (in the form of strings)
I want to use the logs stored inside that variable later on .
Initially, I am trying to get the logs and print them using logging.info()
I tried doing :
def fetch_logs(context):
    ti=context['ti']
    logs=ti.log
    logging.info(logs)

I was expecting it to print the logs for me , but rather a logger object has been printed -
<Logger airflow.task (INFO) > 

I tried converting the logger object to string using str() constructor, but it just converted <Logger airflow.task (INFO) > into strings and not the logs into strings
I tried iterating the Logger Object  , but seems like that was of no help too.
Can someone please help me solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance !!

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_log

Thanks @KamilCuk. That will certainly work . But is there no simpler way to do that .. for example.. using some library present in airflow?

Wich Airflow version are u using ?
What type of log do u need ?
You could use the already mentioned by @KamilCuk Airflow API.
You can interate over DAGrun's or get the information needed using the context:
def check_dump_run(db:str) -> str:
    dag_run = DagRun.find(dag_id='dump_db')
    dag_run = filter(lambda x: x.start_date.strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%d') == date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), dag_run)
    for run in dag_run:
        ti_dump = run.get_task_instance(
            task_id='dump_db_to_base')
        if ti_dump == None:
            continue
        elif ti_dump.current_state()  == 'success':
            return 'success'
        elif ti_dump.current_state() in ['running','scheduled','up_for_retry']:
            return 'running'
    return None

or you could get the logs directly from metadata DB, like airflow.task_instance table.
SELECT state FROM airflow.task_instance 
WHERE dag_id = 'test'
AND task_id = 'fooBar' 
AND DATE(execution_date) = DATE(NOW()) 
AND state = 'success'

Maybe be usefull: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html

I want all the logs that are present in the airflow UI for any particular task instance to be stored (may be in the form of strings) in some variable so that I can process it and use it further.

I don't think that u can do it in a DAG, maybe you need something to stream this logs like ElasticSearch,Prometheus:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html#interleaving-of-logs
As alternative you could iterate over all DAG runs, or as mentioned, use the metadata db.

Ok @Vargas thanks !!
